# comparing 2 IP address in string format in C

Tags: c++, networking

not sure what I am missing.
I am trying to determine if an IP address 172.27.12.32 falls in the range of IP address 20.0.0.0 and 255.255.252.0

What I am doing is the following:

```
std::string one("200.0.0.0");
std::string two("172.27.12.32");
std::string three("255.255.255.255");

long one_addr = inet_addr(one.c_str());
long two_addr = inet_addr(two.c_str());
long three_addr = inet_addr(three.c_str());
```

one_addr is equal to     200
two_addr is equal to     537664428
three_addr is equal to   4294967295

two_addr is greater than one_addr but 172.27.12.32 is not in the range if the min IP address is 200.0.0.0

How do I determine if 172.27.12.32 is not in range of 200.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255?

Comment: Change c tag to c++, given use of `std::string`.

Comment: Why I have a feeling that you got a task wrong. I think you've being asked if IP address 1 is within IP address 2 by mask 3

Comment: all 3 all IP addresses

Comment: If `one_addr` is `200`, then you are using a little-endian machine and the standard comparison operators won't work. This is because a (decimal) IP address `I.J.K.L` is stored in big-endian order, which on a little-endian machine looks like (hex) `0xLLKKJJII`. If you want to compare the addresses as integers, you have to replace `inet_addr` with the `IPtoUInt` function evilruff details below, or something similar.

Comment: `inet_addr()` returns the IPs in network byte order. You could alternatively just use `ntohl()` to convert the IPs to host byte order before comparing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: =) (http://www.stev.org/post/2012/08/09/C++-Check-an-IP-Address-is-in-a-IPMask-range.aspx)

```
uint32_t IPToUInt(const std::string ip) {
    int a, b, c, d;
    uint32_t addr = 0;

    if (sscanf(ip.c_str(), "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a, &b, &c, &d) != 4)
       return 0;

    addr = a << 24;
    addr |= b << 16;
    addr |= c << 8;
    addr |= d;
    return addr;
}
```

Hope thats enough to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

The [`inet_addr()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) returns an `in_addr_t` struct instance:

```
in_addr_t inet_addr(const char *cp);
```

This is often a typedef for a 32-bit integer, which is not always a long on every architecture.

In any case, consider converting `20.0.0.0` and `255.255.252.0` to `in_addr_t` values. Then compare those results with your value of interest. What would you expect?